# Log out from all devices

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts, logout

When I go to logout, it says

```
You have profiles on the following domains within our network:

stackexchange.com
stackoverflow.com
superuser.com

Clicking Log Out will log you out of the following domains on this device:

stackexchange.com
stackoverflow.com
superuser.com

If you're on a shared computer, remember to log out of your Open ID provider (Facebook, Google, Stack Exchange, etc.) as well.
```

So how do I log out on all devices?

Basically, I accidentally did not log out on a computer that is now out of my control. I only logged in via Stack Exchange's login:

[image: Stackoverflow login image]

Now I want to ensure that anyone who happens to get access to that machine cannot use my account. How can I do this?

<sub>Note: There are a **lot** of questions regarding logging out, but it's not clear because they say "clear cookies" or "default is to log out of all devices," but clearly I cannot do the first, and Stack Exchange contradicts the second. I want to know what really happens; perhaps a canonical Q&A would be appropriate for this topic</sub>

Comment: To my understanding (And clearly this differs from platform to platform), previous sessions are generally invalidated when a new one is created, as each user can only be given one session. Of course this depends on implementation - They may 'hold' current active sessions for the next time you log in - But I'd imagine that SE has this kind of check in place to prevent these sort of issues. Else you'd see this being a problem all the time.

Comment: I'd suggest logging into your account from any other device, logging out, clearing your cookies, and then logging back in again. It'd be bad if login sessions couldn't be remotely ended.

Comment: Hold on a moment - `Now I want to ensure that anyone who happens to get access to that machine cannot log out. How can I do this?` - What do you mean? It's not clear what you're trying to do. You're not concerned about anyone else using your account? Your only fear is that they may log you out on other devices?

Comment: @SuperCat Sorry, distracted typing

Comment: Related: *[Tell me how to log out of Stack Exchange OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271924)*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What really happens now is that you're logged out on one device.

I will see where we can fit in a way to log out everywhere, but in the meantime,  to clear out your sessions on all devices: either [contact us](/contact) or flag one of your posts for moderator attention and explain what you'd like the mods to do.

**Update:** We've added a checkbox to the [logout page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/logout) that will allow you to **log out of all devices** if that's your heart's desire. :)

[image]

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed!!