# How can I see which devices are actively logged into Stack Exchange account?

Tags: support, login, stack-exchange-openid, logout

The [user](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user) page of Stack Exchange Open ID gives login history of [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) as well as [Open ID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/), but it registers logout history of only Open ID and not of Stack Exchange.
Is there any way to see the logout history of Stack Exchange? or maybe see the IP address of devices which are not logged out of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Why would you want to know that?

Comment: @Rene Maybe he's worried he's left an internet cafe login active or that a bad actor is using his account somehow

Comment: Ankit, if you use Google to log in they have a page here: https://myaccount.google.com/security

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, I suspect that but in that case going to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/logout and putting the checkmark in *Log out on all devices* would resolve that issue. That option is also available for mods and SE staff btw to reset session on behalf of a user, in case a third party finds something odd.

Comment: @rene Well yes but you wouldn't know whether or not it was necessary.

Comment: If it was necessary it probably was too late ...

Comment: @rene "If it was necessary it probably was too late ..." So everyone should do it everyday at least once, just to be sure.

Comment: @Trilarion if you don't trust yourself, then yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log out from all devices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264062/log-out-from-all-devices)